# Type safety warning when making a generic descending Comparator

Tags: generics

I'm trying to develop a generic descending comparator.
It is working well with String, however it has a warning from eclipse like "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Comparable<T> to T" on the line using compareTo method.
Would anyone help me?

```
package ytp.collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class DescendingComparator<T> implements Comparator<Comparable<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Comparable<T> o1, Comparable<T> o2) {
        int ret = o1.compareTo((T) o2);
        if (ret < 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (ret > 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is because `Comparable<T>` is not necesseraly `T` itself. You can create a lot of different classes which implement `Comparable<T>` but do not extend `T`.

What you need to do is to *restrict* generics parameter:

```
public class DescendingComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int ret = o1.compareTo(o2);
        if (ret < 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (ret > 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also note that reverse comparator functionality is already present in JDK: [Collections.html#reverseOrder(java.util.Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: Thnaks! I figured out my misunderstanding and your code is working well.